# Enable SNMP XenServer 6.5

Tags: firewall, xen, snmp, xenserver

I want to enable ***snmp*** on my servers running **xenserver 6.5.** I've found a few articles with instructions to do so and the whole process seems pretty straight forward but my question is this - ***is there any harm making these changes on host with running virtual machines?***

The instructions require **restarting the firewall**. Will this impact my VM's in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

snmp agent is a process that periodically reads values from the kernel and other places depending on what is configured.

It runs in it's own right and will not disturb your VMs unless you require a reboot as part of the process, which is not normally necessary.

Disabling and re-enabling the firewall should also have no noticeable affect on VMs